# curl command to get the artifact path from circleci does not work if url contains &

Tags: shell, curl, circleci

I am trying to execute curl command like this to get the apk path from circleci

```
 curl -u $CIRCLE_API_KEY: https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github /<username>/<projectname>/latest/artifacts?branch=develop | grep -o 'https://[^"]*' > artifacts.txt
```

it returns

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time       Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left   Speed
100  1229  100  1229    0     0   2063      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2065
```

it works fine and the url like path of the apk i.e https://123-67792073-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/apks/.apk goes to artifacts.txt

However if I add "&filter=success" at the end of the curl url then it does not write to artifacts.txt and does not exit from the command.

```
curl -u $CIRCLE_API_KEY: https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/<username>/<projectname>/latest/artifacts?branch=develop&filter=success | grep -o 'https://[^"]*' > artifacts.txt
```

returns

```
[1] 43348
arsinha$ [ {
  "path" : "apks/<apkname>.apk",
 "pretty_path" : "apks/<apkname>.apk",
  "node_index" : 0,
  "url" : "https://123-67792073-gh.circle-artifacts.com /0/apks/<apkname>.apk"
},]
```

It does not exit as I have to click Ctrl + C to exit. Any reason for this why this happens when the curl url got appended with "&filter=success"

Comment: I'm guessing the & puts the process in the background, so try to escape the command (')                 'curl -u $CIRCLE_API_KEY: https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/<username>/<projectname>/latest/artifacts?branch=develop&filter=success' | grep -o 'https://[^"]*' > artifacts.txt

Comment: oh snap @hardillb  hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your URL in quotes to stop the shell interpreting the `&` as a request to put the command into the background.

e.g.

```
curl -u $CIRCLE_API_KEY: "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/<username>/<projectname>/latest/artifacts?branch=develop&filter=success" | grep -o 'https://[^"]*' > artifacts.txt
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks a lot